# Firebase Dynamic Links always uses first domain url prefix by default for sending authentication email

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-dynamic-links

I have integrated firebase authentication with email in my android app. I have two domain url prefix in dynamic links section. By default, firebase always sends link with first domain url prefix. I tried setting domain url prefix in code by this method -

```
  actionCodeSettings.setDynamicLinkDomain(getString(R.string.dynamic_link_url))
```

but it gives error of **The provided dynamic link domain is not configured or authorized for the current project** Please advice correct way of acheiving this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

if you added a new URL prefix different from the first one you need to manually update **Firebase hosting release history**

you can do it by using [firebase CLI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#install-cli-mac-linux)

1. make sure firebase cli is installed
2. **firebase login** and select your project
3. run **firebase init**
   make sure during project initialization, from the Firebase CLI
   prompts:to select to set up Hosting and Functions
   *Hosting: Configure files for Firebase Hosting and (optionally) set up GitHub Action deploys*
4. continue with the default option

once setup is completed it will generate public folder contained index.html 404.html, .firebaserc and firebase.json

then modify the firebase.json and add the following

```
{
"hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "appAssociation": "AUTO",
    "rewrites": [ { "source": "/links/**", "dynamicLinks": true }, { "source": "/share/**", "dynamicLinks": true } ]
  }
}
enter code here
```

5. **firebase deploy**

please note that links and share are our 2 prefix you can change name to any you want and also note this prefix can be used by different subdomains as well

Answer (score 1):

I'd doing basically the same as in the question, but just in Flutter  setting the `dynamicLinkDomain` property in the `ActionCodeSettings` using the [EmailLinkProvider](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/ui/auth/configuring-providers/#email-link)
eg.

```
dynamicLinkDomain: 'mysuperapp.page.link',
```

and it seems to work fine.

I did **NOT** have to do anything with Firebase CLI updating the hosting history as was suggested in the answer from @fadi-abo-msalam

Given that Flutter would be using the same underlying Android Firebase SDK, perhaps this has been fixed since this question was first asked and it now works for native Android apps as well.